# If $a<b$ and $\frac{c}{a} < \frac{d}{b}$ does that imply $c<d$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Given two numbers $a,b\in (0, \infty)\subset\mathbb{R}$ and two other numbers $c,d\in (0, \infty)\subset\mathbb{R}$ is it sufficient to show that 
>   $$
> \dfrac{c}{a} < \dfrac{d}{b}
> $$
>   in order to prove that $c<d$?

This seems to pass my intuition check of that if you divide by a larger quantity and find that the ratio is larger, the numerator should be larger

My attempt:

$$
a < b \implies \dfrac{a}{b} < 1 
$$
Since 
$$
\dfrac{c}{a} < \dfrac{d}{b} \implies c < \dfrac{ad}{b} < 1 \cdot d \therefore c<d
$$

Does this seem correct or is there an edge case I am missing or logical error?

Comment: this seems correct, as long as $a,b>0$, as you specified

Comment: You need $a < b$, which you've included in the title of your question, but not in the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $a<b$ as a condition, this is correct indeed. If we don't have this condition, $6/3<4/1$ is a counterexample.